# IndexOutOfBoundsException when removing certain items from custom ItemizedOverlay

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay, indexoutofboundsexception

I've been struggling with the following problem for some days now. I have found many threads regarding this topic, but all are a little different or there was no solution.

For my project I created a custom `ItemizedOverlay` and added this to my `MapView`. If I now remove the last item of the list of items I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` claiming that the requested index is equal to the size of the `ArrayList`. I.e. index 2 size 2 or index 0 size 0. From what other topics have told me I have already tried the `populate()` and `setLastFocusedIndex(-1)` methods. These have solved other problems I had, but not this one. When removing other items from the list it works fine, the problem only seems to occur for the last item.

I get the following Logcat output:

```
01-24 16:11:08.091: E/AndroidRuntime(916): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 0, size is 0
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:341)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getItem(ItemizedOverlay.java:419)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.focus(ItemizedOverlay.java:538)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:455)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:346)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:506)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:628)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:852)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-24 16:11:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(916):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What bothers me about this is that it seems to be calling methods from the standard `ItemizedOverlay`. I have not added a normal `ItemizedOverlay` and I don't call super methods in my `itemizedOverlay` except in the constructor. Still the error seems to occur in a normal `ItemizedOverlay`, for which it would make sense that the `ArrayList` is empty.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction since I really feel stuck here. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
public class GameItemOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<Item> {

    private ArrayList<Item> mOverlays = new ArrayList<Item>();


    public GameItemOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
        populate(); 
    }

    public void itemDataReady(){
        mOverlays = GameSession.items;
        setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected Item createItem(int i) {
      return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
      return mOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int i){
        GameSession.remove(mOverlays.get(i).getID()); //Removes the item according to it's position

        setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
        populate();   
        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: do a check before removing: if (index < listSize) list.remove(index). The best solution is to find out why you think you have items in the list when you don't. Have you stepped through?

Comment: post your custom itemizedOverlay code

Comment: @Adrian I did step through and the error does not occur during the removing of the item. Everything goes smoothly the error does not occur until after the remove method completed. That's why I don't think that checking the list will actually be useful. But I'll take another look at it. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to figure the problem. I think the answer to this question is that `ItemizedOverlay` is **not intended** to be used to manage (add and remove) `OverlayItem`s. You can pretty much only add `OverlayItem`s to `ItemizedOverlay` and if you want to change any item, you need to recreate `ItemizedOverlay` (not efficient). To solve this problem you need to manage `ItemizedOverlay`s (with just one `OverlayItem`) in list of `Overlay`s instead of `OverlayItem`s in `ItemizedOverlay`. Something like that:

```
public class SomeActivity extends MapActivity {

    private SomeMapView mView;

    // Rest of the code ...

    private void sendRequest(GeoPoint point)
    {
        List<Overlay> mOverlays = mView.getOverlays();
        // Show red marker
        OverlayItem item    = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello", "world");   
        MarkerItemizedOverlay itemOverlay   = new MarkerItemizedOverlay(drawable, mView);
        itemOverlay.addOverlay(item);
        mOverlays.add(itemOverlay);
    }
}

public class MarkerItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    MapView mView;

    // Rest of the code ...

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        List<Overlay> mOverlays = mView.getOverlays();
        mOverlays.remove(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It sounds good, although it sounds a bit slow too ;) But I do not want to draw any conclusions without trying it. I used a different 'solution' in the end. It isn't elegant, but it works pretty well. You have to add an empty item at the end of the list. This will prevent the error from occurring. You just need to pay more attention when you are adding/removing items.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem, and a workaround.
It seems Google's code up (or down) the call chain gets terribly confused when you shrink the OverlayItem list in the onTap method. Apparently there's some index that isn't updated (or updated too early) - hence the IOOBE.

My solution is based on the fact that I also have a GestureDetector in my ItemizedOverlay subclass (I use the `onSingleTapConfirmed()` for adding items to my map).

- in the `ItemizedOverlay.onTap(int)` function save the index of the OverlayItem just tapped, but don't modify the list (yet)
- in `onSingleTapConfirmed()` check if the 'justTapped' variable is set.

  - If so, remove it from the list
  - call `setLastFocusedIndex(-1)` and `populate()` to update the Overlay internally
  - `invalidate()` the MapView to repaint.
- (optionally) do a little happy dance to celebrate your working code.

Hope this helps anyone!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case i had extended ItemizedOverlay, and inside - was keeping an array of OverlayItems. Each time I panned or zoomed the map, i was clearing the internal list of items, added new ones and then called populate. (By some example I found somewhere). The problem was that the base class - ItemizedOverlay, keeps an internal variable "lastFocusedIndex". After repopulating the list, if it is not reset - the next time you decide to click somewhere in the map - it first decided to remove the focus from the lastSelectedItem.... And now - if your new list contains less items than the value of the lastSelectedItem - then it fails with this exception.

The solution in my case was - after clearing the internal list of OverlayItems, to also invoke setLastFocusedIndex(-1) - this ensures that everything is reset.

Some notes on what was useful for me to debug it:
1. Decompiled ItemizedOverlay from the maps.jar from the android-sdk - Does not help, as this is only an API/Stub jar that does not contain the real classes used @ runtime
2. Using DDMS downloaded system/framwork/com.google.android.maps.jar
3. converted it using dex2jar, and then extracted the correct class file for decompilation